# Learning how to use HTTP requests

Tags: java, http, titanium

I would like to learn about HTTP requests. I checked lot of websites, but I don't know where to start learning and understand it.

I'm learning Java and playing around a lot with Titanium. So it would be great if someone could guide me.

Comment: are you trying to know how it works with Titanium or just learn generally?

Comment: Actually yes. I thought learning generally may help?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a [HTTP tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/index.htm), here's the [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) and here's an [`URLConnection` guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Java, you should also look into Servlets and JSPs. This will give you a more non-abstract view into the HTTP world. You will understand how it is used at an application level.

If you are into turning pages, I suggest [http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Servlets-JSP-Certified/dp/0596005407](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596005407)

If you want online tutorials you can find them by googling "Servlet and jsp tutorials".

An overview can be found here
http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Overview.html